# Self Document This Top Window

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's say I have some random code like below:

```
<script>

    this.fn = (function() {
        var element = document.createElement("div");
        element.innerHTML = Object.keys(self) + 
            "<br />" + Object.keys(window) +
            "<br />" + Object.keys(top);    

        self["document"].body.appendChild(element);
        return arguments.callee;
    })();

</script>
```

Not only having to do with the above code, what's the difference between:
`Self`, `Document`, `This`, `Top`, `Window`?
What's a best use case for each?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`self`** & **`window`** : They both reference the current window (or frame) where the script is located and running.  See [here](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javawindow.html) for details and examples.

**`document`** : References the DOM container, giving you access to the headers and the body contents.  See [here](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadocument.html) for details and examples.

**`this`** : References the JavaScript object under which the code is executed.  JavaScript code and functions written directly inside `<script>` tags have `this` refer to `window`.  If an object's function needs to call a method in the same object, use `this.method_name();`.

**`top`** : References the top-most `window` object in a frame hierarchy.  If you use frames and want to manipulate the whole frameset window from inside a sub-frame, use `top`, e.g. `top.close();` to close the current window containing all the frames.