# Weird self object in window object

Tags: javascript, browser

I can't understand why `window` is under `self` and `self` is under `window` object.

if you go to dev-tools or Firebug and write `window` you got `DOM window` object that `self` is under this object. The weird part is that `window` is under `self` again!

You can write

```
window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self
```

and still you get `window` object!

How?!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145544/self-document-this-top-window

Comment: So you haven't seen self-referencing before? It's quite common in the singleton pattern for example and since javascript lacks private variables directly, you may be able to access it ad infinitum...I'm not saying this "IS" the case, but a use-case or explanation of why it could be

Comment: This is an object not a function. even if there is a self referencing object creating method in JavaScript, I would be more than happy to learn that.

Comment: http://www.google.com/?q=recursion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a response to one of my comments:

> It is a circular reference, so it doesn't end. The compiler only
>   creates one reference. It just happens to be a reference back to the
>   original object on which the reference was created. That's why you can
>   do window.window.window... Like this: var obj = {}; obj.obj = obj;.
>   There's only one reference created but it's a reference back to the
>   original, so you can do obj.obj.obj.obj.obj.obj.obj === obj.

Comment can be seen here: [Is window really global in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript/6680030#comment-8136449)

Comment: OK. var obj = {} and then obj.obj = obj  but how about var obj = {}; obj.self = obj;? Now obj.self.obj return undefined

Comment: @Mohsen: `self` is a property of `window`. `window.self === window`. So it makes sense you'll also get `window.self === window.self`. The comment in my post was only referring to `window.window`.

Comment: Do you know how to reproduce something like this in JavaScript? "parent and self referencing object" :-\

Answer (score 1):

See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.window), and [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self). `window.window` is a reference to itself, so you can repeat `window.window.window ... window`, it will allways return the current window. `self` returns a reference to the current window, so here it's the same, it will allway return the `DOMWindow` Object.

Comment: Thanks you I understand how window.window.window works via the MDN link. So how you make a self referencing object?

Comment: @Mohsen you did it in one of your other comments `var obj = {}; obj.self = obj;`.  Now, `obj.self == obj.self.self == obj.self.self.self == obj`.

Comment: yes, obj.self.self.self... looks right. but self don't have obj in it. so obj.self.obj doesn't work. (how you mark code in comments?!)

Comment: @Moshen: Code in comments are wrapped with the [grave accent character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) >>> ` <<< (between the arrows).

Comment: @Mohsen: Try `obj = {self:{}}; obj.self.obj = obj;` or `obj = {}; obj.self = {obj:obj}`