# Objects inheritance concept in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I just learned about self-referencing objects in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015635/weird-self-object-in-window-object). This is awesome that people here at StackOverflow know every dark corner of JavaScript.

Today I wanted to use my knowledge and use a self-referencing object in my code but I couldn't make it. 
I'm trying to make a self referencing object that have different values in different levels. I want every level of my object have the main properties that I'm defining in level one and level two and below have all properties of level two and so on...
Let's see what I'm trying to do:

`obj` is an object that is self referencing, it means `obj.obj` refer to `obj` and so on...
I want  to have a property in `obj.obj` but not in `obj`, like `obj.obj.newProp = "myString"` and then every level below the level two should have the `newProp`.
This is the code I wrote that I'm sure is not current!

```
var obj = {},
    obj.obj = obj,
    obj.obj.newProp = "myString";
```

But when I look at obj it contains `"myString"`. How can I prevent `obj` refering to `obj.obj`?

Comment: If it is self-referencing, then it is the very same object. You cannot have one level have a property and not the other. (a) I don't think self-referencing is the right approach here. (b) Inheritance is something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"I want to have a property in obj.obj but not in obj"*

But they're the *same object*. You can't have and not have a specific property on the same object at the same time.

```
 // obj is a reference to__
 //                       |
var obj = {}; //<---------|
//         ^
//         |----------------------------------------------
//                                       |                |
obj.obj = obj; // "obj" is a property on | that refers to |
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you're talking about inheritance, then you need to set one object as the prototype object of another. There are a couple of different approaches.

If you're only supporting modern JavaScript environments, you can use `Object.create()`.

```
var obj1 = { prop1:'value 1' };

var obj2 = Object.create( obj1 );

obj2.prop2 = 'value 2';

obj1.prop1; // value 1
obj1.prop2; // undefined

// obj2 inherits the properties of obj1 through the prototype chain
obj2.prop1; // value 1
obj2.prop2; // value 2
```

---

If you're supporting older browsers, then you can use a constructor function, and set the `prototype` object of the constructor to `obj1`, and all objects created from the constructor will have `obj1` in its prototype chain.

```
function MyConstructor() {}

var obj1 = { prop1:'value 1' };

MyConstructor.prototype = obj1;

var obj2 = new MyConstructor();

obj2.prop2 = 'value 2';

obj1.prop1; // value 1
obj1.prop2; // undefined

// obj2 inherits the properties of obj1 through the prototype chain
obj2.prop1; // value 1
obj2.prop2; // value 2
```

Comment: You might be able to if you put it in a box ;) (But then you cannot access the property. It might be there or not... you will never know).

Comment: How you reach to an approach like what I described?

Comment: @Mohsen: It depends ultimately on how you want to use it. Are you referring to *nested* objects where you access a different object from the property of another? Or do you want a child object to inherit all the properties of a parent so you can reference the parent's properties as though they were part of the child? What's the end goal with your code?

Comment: I want to simulate something like "class". I think second scenario is mine

Comment: @Moshen: Yes, you don't really have classes in JavaScript, but you do have the prototype object chain. The two examples I added will *generally*  give the same result, but the second one you'll be able to run in more browsers if that's your target environment. There are ways to emulate the first one in older browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have different values at different level. Since `obj.obj is obj`, meaning, `obj.obj` holds a reference to `obj`, rather than a copy, this means any change to `obj` will change any reference to it.

Imagine an object, which we will call `foo`. `bar` and `obj` both holds reference to `foo`. Any change to the properties of `foo`, `bar`, or `obj` will change the value of the others. Example:

```
var foo = {};
var bar = foo;
var obj = foo;
bar.lol = 'mew';
bar.lol == foo.lol == obj.lol
```